# Accessing Information in an IList after linq query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have a class mapped to an SQL table and can perform a Linq query ok.  I need to access some of the information in Products and modify data such as Price before returning as a JSon object.

The problem is a i cant access any of the information in Products.  Could someone please advise how i could achieve this?

Class:

```
 <Table(Name:="dbo.VXPartsData")>
    Public Class VXPartsData
        <Key()>
        Public Property PartNo() As String
        Public Property CustPart() As String
        Public Property ShortDesc() As String
        Public Property Part() As String
        Public Property Price() As Decimal?
        Public Property DiscCode() As String
        Public Property Kit() As Boolean
        Public Property VXCODE() As String
    End Class
```

Linq query:

```
   Dim Products = DB.VXPartsData.Where(Function(e) e.PartNo = pair.Key).ToList()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot access"? What does `Products(0).PartNo` return?

Comment: Access them in the Linq query or access them after in `Products`?. Have you tried `Products(0).` to access the properties. `(0)` being the first item in `Products`.